# How to remove a set of GMSMarker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, gmsmapview

I am using this code to set multiple annotations in GoogleMapView.

```
- (void)setDriverAnnotationsWith:(NSMutableArray *)drivers
{
    if (drivers.count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (NSDictionary *driverAttributes in drivers)
    {
        float latitude = [[driverAttributes objectForKey:@"latitude"]floatValue];
        float longitude = [[driverAttributes objectForKey:@"longitude"]floatValue];
        float angle = [[driverAttributes objectForKey:@"driver_car_direction_angle"]floatValue];

        GMSMarker *driverMarker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        [driverMarker setPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)];
        NSString *carImage = [Utilities getVehicleImage:[[driverAttributes objectForKey:@"car_type"]integerValue]];
        [driverMarker setIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:carImage]];
        driverMarker.rotation = angle;
        driverMarker.map = _googleMapView;
    }
}
```

Also I have some other markers in map. But I need to remove markers created from the above function when a UITableViewCell is tapped.
How can I achieve that?
Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the marker from the map, you can set the `GMSMarker` map to `nil`. For example:

```
driverMarker.map = nil
```

You can check the Maps SDK for iOS documentation for more info: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#remove_a_marker

You can utilize the touch events in iOS if you want to remove the marker when `UITableViewCell` is tapped/touched. You can check the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_touches_in_your_view

You may also particularly read on the `touchesBegan(_:with:)` event: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan